# CountDownTimer in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am experimenting with CountDownTimer in jetpack compose with the following code

```
@Composable
fun Timer() {
    val millisInFuture: Long = 10 * 1000 // TODO: get actual value

    val timeData = remember {
        mutableStateOf(millisInFuture)
    }

    val countDownTimer =
        object : CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                Log.d("TAG", "onTick: ")
                timeData.value = millisInFuture
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
               
            }
        }
    
    DisposableEffect(key1 = "key") {
        countDownTimer.start()
        onDispose {
            countDownTimer.cancel()
        }
    }

    Text(
        text = timeData.value.toString()
    )
}
```

In the logcat I am able to see the timer is ticking but the UI is not updating .
Please explain why there is on recomposition on changing the value of state variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Within the CountDownTimer, instead of setting millisInFuture, you should set millisUntilFinished. That variable holds the updated value, the millisInFuture never changes

```
timeData.value = millisUntilFinished
```

Comment: Countdowntimer has issues with cancel() not working. Consider avoiding.

Answer (score 4):

simple CountDownTimer Just for second

```
var timer by remember { mutableStateOf(durationSeconds) }
LaunchedEffect(key1 = timer) {
    if (timer > 0) {
        delay(1_000)
        timer -= 1
    }
}


Text(
    text = timer.toString()
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code to implement a Countdown timer:

```
val time = (timerDate.time).minus(Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis)
var timer by remember { mutableStateOf(time) }
  LaunchedEffect(key1 = timer) {
      if (timer > 0) {
          delay(1000L)
          timer -= 1000L
       }
     }
  val secMilSec: Long = 1000
  val minMilSec = 60 * secMilSec
  val hourMilSec = 60 * minMilSec
  val dayMilSec = 24 * hourMilSec
  val hours = (time % dayMilSec / hourMilSec).toInt()
  val minutes = (time % dayMilSec % hourMilSec / minMilSec).toInt()
  val seconds = (time % dayMilSec % hourMilSec % minMilSec / secMilSec).toInt()

Text(text = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds))
```

Answer (score 0):

Composable only recompose when there is state change either from the Composable function param or by the value change of `State<T>` inside the Composable itself like `mutableStateOf()` or `mutableStateListOf()`. In your case, you haven't start the `countDownTimer` itself. Try to call `countDownTimer.start()` inside the `DisposableEffect`. Second you set the timeData with the wrong value, try to set it with `millisUntilFinished`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to make a delay that acts like a `countDownTimer` in seconds as below:

```
@Composable
private fun Timer(
    waitingTime: Long = WAITING_TIME_MILLIS,
    onFinish: () -> Unit
) = LaunchedEffect(waitingSeconds) {
    delay(waitingSeconds)
    onFinish()
}
```